# Displaying a figure on web browser, based on user input, using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I want to display a Plotly figure on my web browser, based on user input, using python flask. I am using "Python - HTTP Server" and I run the command:

python -m http.server

I have app.py that I use for the python code and routes:

```
from flask import Flask, config, render_template, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly
import plotly.express as px


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@cross_origin()

@app.route('/callback', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cb():
    return gm(request.args.get('data'))
   
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('localhost:8000/chartsajax.html',  graphJSON=gm())

def gm(country='United Kingdom'):
    df = pd.DataFrame(px.data.gapminder())
    fig = px.line(df[df['country']==country], x="year", y="gdpPercap")
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    return graphJSON

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=False)
```

I have my HTML file, chartsajax.HTML, that is being displayed:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function cb(selection) {
            $.getJSON({
                url: "/callback", data: { 'data': selection }, success: function (result) {
                    Plotly.react('chart', result, {});;
                }
            });

            
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="font-family:arial, sans-serif">
    <h1>GDP per Capita Over Time</h1>
    <h2>Choose your country</h2>
    <p>Make sure you spell it correctly with capital letter(s), e.g. United Kingdom</p>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onchange="cb(this.value)">
    <div id="chart" class="chart"></div>
    <div id="png_chart"></div>
</body>

<script>
    cb("United Kingdom");
</script>
</html>
```

Here is a screen shot of the directory structure within my local host:

[image]

When I start the local server:

[image]

After I add: localhost:8000/chartsajax.html
to the web address bar, everything is fine:

[image]

[image]

But, when I add: http://localhost:8000/chartsajax.html
I get the HTML page displaying the field that text need to be entered into to get the plot to show. But, I get a 304 error.

[image]

When I add United Kingdom to the input field, I get a 404 error:

[image]

I have been trying every combination of code I know to use but cant get the plot to show. I feel like its either directory structure related or something going on with request.args.get('data'). Any input would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Edit:

After taking Arif's advice and adding a templates folder to the app.py directory, and pasting:

C:/Users/......./Plotly_API/templates/chartsajax.html

into the web address field, I get two errors:

[image]

These errors, from early on, when building the code, is why I switched over to using "Python - HTTP Server". That got rid of the error messages but created the other problems, above, in this post.

Edit 2:

Everything Arif suggested worked after I added:

localhost:8000

to the web address field.

Thanks, Arif!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your html file should be inside a directory named "templates" for flask to render properly. Create a folder named "templates" inside the same directory as app.py, and then keep your html file inside the templates folder.

Now, when you run the server instead of typing "python -m http.server", type "python app.py" in the terminal.

Using "python -m http.server" to start a simple HTTP server is an incorrect usage of the Flask app, as it serves the files from the current working directory, which is separate from your Flask application.

Also, refactor your code in the following section:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/callback', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cb():
    return gm(request.args.get('data'))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('chartsajax.html', graphJSON=gm())

def gm(country='United Kingdom'):
    df = pd.DataFrame(px.data.gapminder())
    fig = px.line(df[df['country'] == country], x="year", y="gdpPercap")
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    return graphJSON

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=False)
```

After refactoring, your app is working fine, and showing the plot as below:
[screenshot of running app.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrK54.png)

Comment: Arif, thank you so much for taking the time to answer! Everything appears to work up until I add data to the field. When I add "United Kingdom" to the text field I get errors within my HTML inspector.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/callback?data=United%20Kingdom' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.        chartsajax.html:1

Comment: GET file:///C:/callback?data=United%20Kingdom net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: I just figured it out! I had to put:

localhost:8000

Into the web address.